# how to minimise load time of automatic slider of an image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:flipInterval="1000"
    android:autoStart="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/wow_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/transparent_water"/>

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/tr"/>
  </ViewFlipper>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

> I'm using this xml its working fine but it takes time to load slider.And I want to use 4 to 5 images more.Any suggestions
>
> I actually get at the of running and starting the app

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:flipInterval="500"
    android:autoStart="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/wow_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/transparent_water"/>

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/tr"/>
  </ViewFlipper>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these line :

```
viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(YOUR TIME);
```